# Debugging JDO error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

My application is throwing this error:

```
Error : An error occurred trying to instantiate an instance of the API adapter "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter" 
(perhaps you dont have the requisite datanucleus-api-XXX jar in the CLASSPATH?) : 
{1}
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Error : 
An error occurred trying to instantiate an instance of the API adapter "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter" (perhaps you dont have the requisite datanucleus-api-XXX jar in the CLASSPATH?) : 
{1}
...
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Although my application do have `datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-release.jar`

What could be the reason if not missing jars?

EDIT:

This is what have been suggested to fix this issue:

> This is a sporadic error that happens from time to time on any
>   persistable class, but moreso on ones that are used a lot in parallel.
>   It happens in JDO and JPA, and it seems as though the local datastore
>   locks a particular table / entity group and forgets to release it;
>   thus causing all subsequent calls to ds operations to fail. I
>   generally don't have to restart eclipse; just stopping then starting
>   the server tends to fix the problem, if not, a full refresh/clean
>   build will do the trick.

However, I have already restarted my GAE server and re-run my application still getting the same error.

**Here is the complete** [POM.xml](http://pastebin.com/JAbwXjHA)

**Here is the complete** [stack trace.](http://pastebin.com/1Rm7UUF0)

Comment: As already said, look at the log, stack trace etc etc.

Comment: Yes, looking at the stack trace I can see the error rooting from QueuedThreadPool.java, and searching the internet this is what people are suggesting: "This is a sporadic error that happens from time to time on any persistable class"

Comment: @DataNucleus I have edited the question to show the advised solution

Comment: 3.0.0-release is not the latest version, there are many 3.0.x versions after that. Errors of that sort are down to other things and not "sporadic problems" (unless Jetty is not providing a correct classpath under some circumstances), but then posting the full stack trace would tell more about that ... once you've updated to use recent versions

Comment: Ok I see, I will have to update to the latest version and see if that will fix the problem hopefully.

Comment: I did updated the libraries to higher version number but still getting the same error.

Comment: So you haven't got datanucleus-api-jdo.jar or some dependent jar in the CLASSPATH, likely jdo-api.jar. NoClassDefFoundError means just that and nothing else

Comment: Thanks. Now I have this error: {"exception":"Persistent class \"Class org.myapp.model.Account does not seem to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output.\" has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use latest versions. Include all dependencies (jdo-api, datanucleus-api-jdo). Read docs for what needs to be in the CLASSPATH (enhanced versions of your classes, for example).